# Select n random number from a sorted list of numbers

Tags: python

I have a list of numbers in sorted order. `There may be gaps between consecutive numbers`. I wrote the following code to find 50K random numbers from that list, however it takes too much time. Is there any efficient version for this?

```
def selectNrandomValsFromAList(mylist, n):
    retval = []
    randomchoice = random.choice
    mylistremove = mylist.remove
    retvalappend = retval.append
    for i in range(n):
        value = randomchoice(mylist)
        mylistremove(value)
        retvalappend(value)
    return(retval)



mylist = range(2000000)
n =50000
selectNrandomValsFromAList(mylist,n)
```

Comment: Also, `random.choice` and `random.sample`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Use [random.sample](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample):

> Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population
>   sequence. Used for random sampling without replacement.

```
>>> import random
>>> l = range(20)
>>> random.sample(l, 10)
[6, 15, 13, 3, 2, 4, 14, 17, 7, 10]
```

Comment: Thanks I was thinking that the function does not expect `gaps`. I was so silly. Thanks